# How do I resolve using 32 bit program with 64 bit database driver?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, windows-10

I'm sure some will say this questions is off topic, but it is truly about programming since I wrote this program and I need to get it working on Windows 10.

I wrote an application in VB.Net and compiled it for "AnyCPU". So it would work in both 32 bit and 64 bit environments. The program communicates with a MySQL database so I load both the 32 bit ODBC drivers and the 64 bit ODBC drivers during the installation. However, one piece of the program uses Crystal Reports for outputting a report. The piece of Crystal I'm using only runs in the 32 bit work space.

The MySQL database installed is 64 bit due to the 64 bit OS.

Everything works harmoniously in Windows_7 (64 bit), but the same configuration does not work in Windows_10 (64 bit). In Windows 10 when the user tries to run the Crystal program to view a report, MySQL throws an error that it can't find the ODBC driver in

"C:\Program Files(x86)\MYSQL\Connector ODBC 5.3\myodbc5a.dll"

Of course the driver is there, but this error is usually due to the wrong bit version of the driver being installed.

The 64 bit version is installed in

"C:\Program Files\MYSQL\Connector ODBC 5.3\myodbc5a.dll"

Is this a Windows 10 issue or something else? How can I get MySQL to use the correct driver location?

Comment: `Of course the driver is there` - [double check that](http://superuser.com/q/419832/52365). Also double check what bitness your program's process shows in the task manager on both Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Comment: compare versions of these files.

Comment: The correct versions were in place but the 32 bit version was missing myodbc5c.dll which was not showing in the error. I only noticed it was missing after getting an error trying to install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help anyone else or not, but basically I went back to ensure that the correct versions of the ODBC drivers were installed in their correct locations. So I uninstalled both versions of the ODBC drivers and tried to reinstall them. In doing this, I saw that the MySQL installer would only let me install one bit version of the driver but not both. My program installs both drivers from the command line in silent mode. But when duplicating my installation method, I noticed that the 32 bit drivers were not being installed correctly when run from the script. But since it installs in silent mode, I never noticed. All of the 32 bit driver dlls were there, including the one shown in the error message, however it was missing 2 dlls that did not get installed properly during the silent installation.

So using the MySQL installer, I tried to install both bit versions of the drivers but as I mentioned above it wouldn't let me. If I installed one version then went back and tried the other version it complained that both versions were already installed. So I had to trick it by installing one version then renaming the folder and then uninstalling it and installing the other version. Once the second version was installed, I went back and renamed the original version's folder back to its original name. That way both bit versions were in thier proper place. However, looking at the installer, it showed that only one version was installed (the one I installed last).

I'm still not sure why my silent installation failed. The error was reminiscent of the error you get when the C++ redistributable needs to be installed, but I tried this and it did not solve the problem. So my immediate problem has been resolved. If I figure out my installation issue, I'll come back and update this answer.